# Trying dynamic carousel slider using repeater asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Below is my carousel slider inside repeater which is not working.

```
           <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                  <div class="upload-h4">
                  <h4>Mark Attendance</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Attendance" runat="server">

                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="item active">
                   <img src="Trainer_Images/attendance1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                  <div class="carousel-caption caption-bg">
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-4">Submitted Date:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">01/11/2019</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">Latitude:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">17.4428449</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">Longitute:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">78.47995379999998</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">Event Type:</div>
                   <div class="col-md-8">Mark Attendance</div>

                  </div>

                  </div>

                  </div>
                 </div>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                 <div class="item">
                 <img src="Trainer_Images/attendance2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                 <div class="carousel-caption caption-bg">
                 <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">Submitted Date:</div>
                 <div class="col-md-8">02/11/2019</div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">Latitude:</div>
                 <div class="col-md-8">17.4428449</div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">Longitute:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">78.47995379999998</div>


                  <div class="col-md-4">Event Type:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">Mark Attendance</div>
                  </div>

                  </div>

                   </div>
                </div>
               </AlternatingItemTemplate>

               </asp:Repeater>



                </div>

               <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
             <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
             </a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Below is my html slider which working fine.

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
                                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

                                      <div class="upload-h4">
                                         <h4>Mark Attendance</h4>
                                       </div>

                                      <div class="carousel-inner">

                                                        <div class="item active">
                                          <img src="Trainer_Images/attendance1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption caption-bg">
                                             <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-12">

                                                   <div class="col-md-4">Submitted Date:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">01/11/2019</div>

                                                  <div class="col-md-4">Latitude:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">17.4428449</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-4">Longitute:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">78.47995379999998</div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-4">Event Type:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">Mark Attendance</div>

                                               </div>

                                             </div>

                                           </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img src="Trainer_Images/attendance2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption caption-bg">
                                             <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-12">
                                                   <div class="col-md-4">Submitted Date:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">02/11/2019</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-4">Latitude:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">17.4428449</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-4">Longitute:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">78.47995379999998</div>


                                                   <div class="col-md-4">Event Type:</div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-8">Mark Attendance</div>
                                               </div>

                                             </div>

                                           </div>
                                        </div>


                                      </div>

                                      <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
```

I am getting below image output when i will use using repeater but using html working fine.

[image]

Please help i am trying using repeater for dynamic fetching data of images please help to out this issue thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To display dynamic data, a repeater must be bound to some sort of data source for that dynamic data, and your code doesn't show where you are doing that. If you are, you should add that code to your question.

If you are not binding to a data source, that's probably why nothing is showing up. Without a data source, no items are ever getting added to the repeater, and the ItemTemplate will never be used, so you won't see any of that content from the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Firstly i am passing statically image and data in repeater, but statically only not coming na, i know i have bound from database. @erastl